# Wince Device Driver

Tags: windows-ce

I am trying to connect my POS Terminal(WinCE Secure Multi-Application Operating System,200 MHz ARM 920T 32 bit CPU) to my windows 7 PC. The issue is i am getting a device driver software issue and the device is not been recognized. I didn't got any installation CD or software with the product.I couldn't find a suitable driver for the same in the web and  would need to install the CAB files through WMDC into the device so that i can automate the product testing. Can someone  please  advice in fixing this driver issue and direct me on how to establish the connection. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

This can be a complex task.  First, the connection type (serial, USB, Ethernet, other) is important.  I'm going to assume USB, as that feels like what you're probably talking about (you should edit and clarify though).

For USB to work, you need drivers on both ends - the device and the PC - and they need to cooperate.  For Windows CE devices and USB, the common way (though not only option) is to use ActiveSync.  There is an out-of-the-box client application driver for Windows CE (repllog.exe) - though it requires the OEM actually plumbs it through to the transport driver.  For the desktop (Vista and later) you would use [Windows Mobile Device Center](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931937) (WMDC).

You might simply be able to install WMDC and you're off and running, but it's always possible that the OEM disabled that, since you might not want someone to connect a PC to a POS system and subvert the normal operation.  Have you asked the device OEM?